# How BitSet admit long array with length 6?

Tags: java, bitset

BitSet internally uses long array of size 6.

But it can contain 2^31-1 bits.

long = 64 bit

6 longs = 64 * 6. But is much less than 2^31-1. Please explain this trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal array which stores the values expands if necessary, just like an `ArrayList` would do for objects. Your statement is therefore false.

There is a hard limit of `2^31-1` (bits) for the size, but that's only because the operations (`set`, `flip`, etc.) take the index parameter as an `int`. Which is probably big enough for most use cases.